# GUI hangs upon bash input request

Tags: git, bash, git-gui

I have a hook for git that checks some condtions, and, if something is wrong, writes "Continue? [y/N]" and waits for the input. When something is commited from console, everything works as expected. But when I am trying to commit using some GUI tool, for example, `git gui`, it hangs. May be because it cannot "input" anything or detect that input is needed.
How can I overcome this?

Comment: maybe the PS1 variable [http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html] contains a slow command. Try `export PS1="$ "` and see

Comment: @ElvisCiotti Problem has been solved using self-made GUI application that displays dialog with buttons. But there are some already built tools like `dialog`: http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog

Answer (score 1):

Rather than asking for confirmation via a hook, it might be a better design to just reject the commit if the conditions aren't met, possibly producing a message explaining why, and let the user fix and retry. That's certainly easier than trying to figure out whether the user is coming from a terminal, `git gui`, eclipse/egit, jgit, or the many myriad other possible git interfaces, and trying to adjust individually to each one.